# Android app chooser doesn't show while opening website

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have created a browser application with below code,
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".CustomBrowserActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.google.com" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now I have another application which tries to open google home page `http://www.google.com`

```
Intent intentToOpen = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentToOpen, "Load http://www.google.com with: ");
```

Now, whenever above code is executed, default browser is opened, rather than my custom browser.

Any help would be appreciated.